# How to select only numbers from file names in bash using regex

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a directory with files of the pattern:

```
SNAFU12.jpg
SNAFU1.jpg
SNAFU123.jpg
```

I tried using this code, but produces no output:

```
 for f in *.jpg; do
   regex="/\d/g"
   file="f:5:6"
   if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
   fi
 done
```

My expected output should be:

```
12
1
23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Regex pattern is not matching anything because it is trying to match two `/`s, which are directory separator for *nix, and no filename would contain that. I am assuming `/.../g` comes from your JavaScript (or other) Regex practice, no?

Do:

```
for i in *.jpg; do [[ $i =~ ([0-9]+)\.jpg$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done
```

`bash` Regexp does not support `\d` keyword for the character class `[0-9]`. So better use `[0-9]`, if you want to depend on your `locale`, use character class `[:digit:]`:

```
for i in *.jpg; do [[ $i =~ ([[:digit:]]+)\.jpg$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done
```

**Example:**

```
$ for i in *.jpg; do [[ $i =~ ([0-9]+)\.jpg$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done
123
12
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the `ls` output of the folder that contains the files:

```
ls SNAFU* | sed -e 's/SNAFU\|.jpg//g'
```