# How can I extract a number from a file name occurring before a given string?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, filenames

I have lots of files

```
101s18-exam02--100-booklets.pdf
MATH232 Exam 01 99 booklets.pdf
35BOOKLETS.pdf
```

I want to write a command that extracts the number from each file occurring before the word "booklets" (where case is ignored). So, the output of running this command should result in

```
$ bash mycommand.sh 101s18-exam02--100-booklets.pdf
100

$ bash mycommand.sh MATH232 Exam 01 99 booklets.pdf
99

$ bash mycommand.sh 35BOOKLETS.pdf
35
```

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: [How to select only numbers from file names in bash using regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/338224/22142)... just change the regex to `([0-9]+)[^0-9]*booklet` and adjust the code to your needs... you need `shopt -s nocasematch` before that though if you want to ignore case...

Comment: Besides (nothing), space, and dash, what other characters can exist between the desired number and the string “booklets”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash's conditional testing operator `[[` can compare filenames to a regular expression and extract parenthesized expressions:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
for f in *booklets*
do
  [[ $f =~ ([[:digit:]]+)[^[:digit:]]?booklets ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

That will loop over every file that matches has the (case-insensitive) word "booklets" in it in the current directory. If you want something to execute against a single file at a time, you could simplify the above and put it in a script or a function:

```
extractnumber ()
(
    shopt -s nocaseglob
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then echo "File $1 not found!"; return 1; fi
    [[ $1 =~ ([[:digit:]]+)[^[:digit:]]?booklets ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
)
```

... and then call it:

```
$ extractnumber 35BOOKLETS.pdf
35
$ extractnumber MATH232\ Exam\ 01\ 99\ booklets.pdf
99
$ extractnumber 101s18-exam02--100-booklets.pdf
100
$ extractnumber foobar
File foobar not found!
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a `grep` implementation that knows the `-o` flag, and `tr`:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\n' "$@" | grep -oiE '[0-9]+[^0-9]*booklets' | tr -dc '0-9\n'
```

This is an `sh` script (not `bash`, though it would work with `bash` too). It assumes that no string passed to it on the command line has a literal newline embedded in it.

The extended regular expression `[0-9]+[^0-9]*booklets` will match any string that looks like `<integer><zero or more non-digit characters><"booklets">` and with `-o`, this is exactly what will be returned from `grep`.  The `tr` simply deletes anything in the output from `grep` that is not a digit or newline.

The `tr` could be replaced by `sed 's/[^0-9].*//'`, which deletes everything from the first non-digit character in the string.

Testing it:

```
$ sh script.sh 101s18-exam02--100-booklets.pdf
100
$ sh script.sh "MATH232 Exam 01 99 booklets.pdf"
99
$ sh script.sh 35BOOKLETS.pdf
35

$ sh script.sh 101s18-exam02--100-booklets.pdf "MATH232 Exam 01 99 booklets.pdf" 35BOOKLETS.pdf
100
99
35
```

Note that strings with spaces in them needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

I have done by below mentioned `pythonscript.py`  and pipelined the output to search required matches. I could have using only python but I wished to use grep so pipelined the output

The input file called `inputfile` file:

```
101s18-exam02--100-booklets.pdf
MATH232 Exam 01 99 booklets.pdf
35BOOKLETS.pdf
```

Usage:

```
python pythonscript.py |grep -o "^[0-9]*"
```

The `pythonscript.py` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
o = open('inputfile','r')
k=re.compile(r'\d{2,3}\s?-?booklets',re.IGNORECASE)
for g in o:
    u=re.search(k,g)
    if u:
       print u.group()
```

The  Output:

```
100
99
35
```

Comment: It looks to me like they're trying to extract digits from the file name, not the file contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed

```
sed -E '
  s/^/ /
  s/.*[^0-9]([0-9]+).?[bB][oO]{2}[kK][lL][eE][tT][sS].*/\1/
' infile
```

Comment: It looks to me like they're trying to extract digits from the file *name*, not the file *contents*.

Comment: @JeffSchaller if infile = the list of files given by OP, I get 100 99 35